# ZeroMQ reordering

Tags: java, zeromq

I'm using DEALER (outboudSocket), ROUTER (inboundSocket) sockets to connect two applications on local machine. The protocol used is tcp. I'm using java zeromq bindings and just one NIO thread:

```
ZMQ.Context zmqContext = ZMQ.context(1);
```

I have one thread on the sending side, taking messages from blocking queue in while loop and performing send:

```
private void send(String msg){
     outboundSocket.sendMore("");
     outboundSocket.send(msg);
}
```

And one thread on the receiving side, taking message from socket in while loop and putting it to blocking queue:

```
private String recv(){
    inboundSocket.recv();
    inboundSocket.recv();
    return new String(inboundSocket.recv());
}
```

Is there any gurantee that messages will never be reordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### MESSAGE DELIVERY

There are many explicit warnings not to assume any kind of guaranteed message delivery ( read the excellent book "Code Connected: Volume 1" on this subject )

### ORDER OF MESSAGES

However the order of incoming messages ( underscored by a single NIO thread ) shall be kept, as no lottery, no round-robin merry-go-round logic takes place on a 1-to-1 connected apps on buffer management ( still there is no policy to avoid any other 3rd party `.connect()`-ing the  .bind()-exposed socket access point )

### Nota bene on a Transport Class overhead

you need not waste resources to deploy the TCP-stack overhead on a pair of just a localhost-connected apps. Did you experiment with the speed/performance comparison if the transport classes available `{ inproc: | TCP: | ... }`